# Is there a way to make @suffix on task basename in Apache Ant case-insensitive?

Tags: ant, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

in my build file, I have declared:

```
<basename property="filename" file="${args.input}" suffix="XML"/>
```

where `${args.input}` is passed in through an Oxygen transformation scenario, ex `-Dargs.input="${cfd}\PMC-min.XML"`

`${filename}` returns `PMC-min`, which is the desired output. I want the file name without any extension.

However, after discovering an error I realized that

```
<basename property="filename" file="${args.input}" suffix="xml"/>
```

was returning `PMC-min.XML`. So `@suffix` is case-sensitive.

I could change `${args.input}` to `${cfd}\PMC-min` (which would require other changes to the build file), or just make sure the extension case of `${args.input}` matches `@suffix` in the scenario. But I was wondering if there was a case-insensitive way to retrieve the filename without the extension in ant? (It doesn't seem to matter if the case of the actual file's extension is different, only the parameters have to match).

Answer (score 0):

One way that might work for you is to use a [`<mappedresources>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#mappedresources) "collection of one", something like this:

```
<mappedresources id="converted">
  <string value="${args.input}" />
  <chainedmapper>
    <flattenmapper />
    <globmapper casesensitive="false" from="*.xml" to="*" />
  </chainedmapper>
</mappedresources>

<echo message="file_name=${toString:converted}" />
```

The echo is just to illustrate how to reference the resource.

In the above:

- the string resource specifies the input value
- the chained mapper combines two mapping steps to alter the string:

  - a flattenmapper removes the directory part
  - a globmapper removes the suffix, ignoring case.